# Images are not running in .jar

Tags: java, image, jar, path

I'm making a Java project, and now that it is finished, i want to make a .jar version.
But when i run the .jar version, the images are not included. I'm working with Netbeans on Mac.

I try to make this code :

```
private static String chemin = System.getProperty("user.dir");
private String fond_path = chemin+"/src/hepta/Images/FondParametres.png";

fondPanels = new ImageIcon(fond_path);
```

But it looks like not working in the .jar version, even if the images are at the same place than before !

My questin is, why is it different because the path is available ?

(I precise that i make some researches, to find some codes like this :

```
URL imageurl = getClass().getResource("/images/images2.gif"); 
Image myPicture = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(imageurl);
JLabel piclabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon( myPicture ));
```

but i don't really understand the difference)

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is, the first is a file reference.  The path points to a file within the file system.

The second is a resource reference, that points to a entry within a zip file, that Java knows how to read.

When you look at the folder that contains the `.jar` file, you will not there is no directory `src/hepta/Images`.  This means if you were to try and use the file reference, Java would be unable to locate the file in question.

Instead, you need to tell Java to look up the resource, based on it's class path/search path, which points to a resource that has been embedded inside the `.jar` file - which is just a zip file with some extras...

Comment: And last question, if i want to give to someone my project, i must include only a .zip which contains the .jar and the project, right ?

Comment: You only need to give them the `.jar` and any possible dependencies.  Zipping the jars is optional...